# Force user to agree to terms and conditions before using the system on portal?

Tags: apex, visualforce, authentication

I have a portal app and when a user logs in I want to force them to agree to the latest terms and conditions (t&cs) before using the system.

So once a user logs in I check to see if they have agreed to our latest t&cs (via a custom object relationship), if they haven't I send them to an agree page. The issue is they can just go to any page without agreeing to it.

I have come up with 2 alternatives to fix this. One is implementing a before_filter type logic that we can hook into every page in our app --- see here --[before_filter for all pages & controllers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20513/before-filter-for-all-pages-controllers)

The other option is to log them in, check this, then log them out and take them to the agreement page and make them re-login and agree. The problem with this is there is no server side logout --- [apex method for logout from force.com site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/apex-method-for-logout-from-force-com-site/9500#9500)

I dont love either of these options and was hoping someone has a better idea/approach.

Comment: Have you thought about making the agreement page not have sidebar/header so they couldn't easily navigate away from it?